# Add methods to class Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have two classes, one **Car**:

```
var config = require('./configuration');

module.exports.Car = function(){}

module.exports.Car.prototype.set_tires = config.set_tires;
module.exports.Car.prototype.remove_tires = config.remove_tires; 

module.exports.Car.prototype.drive = function(){console.log("BRUMMM BRUMMM")}
```

and a **Motorbike**:

```
var config = require('./configuration');

module.exports.Motorbike = function(){}

module.exports.Motorbike.prototype.set_tires = config.set_tires;
module.exports.Motorbike.prototype.remove_tires = config.remove_tires; 

module.exports.Motorbike.prototype.drive = function(){ console.log("BR BR BRUUMM")}
```

As you see both implement methods from **Configuration** that looks like this:

```
module.exports.set_tires = function(tires){
    this.tires = tires;
}

module.exports.remove_tires = function(){
    console.log("The " + this.tires + " Tires will be removed");
    this.tires = null;
}
```

**I wonder if there's another nicer way to implement the methods??** In this example I gave you there are only two shared methods, but with more you can easily lose the overview. **Also I would like to know if there is a nicer way to not repeat `module.exports` to often?**

Comment: Why do you not assign module.exports to a varible? Then you could spare yourself from writing module.exports again for each new method or property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to merge two objects. You can do this with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if available:

```
Object.assign(Motorbike.prototype, config);
```

See [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/218196) for alternative ways.

Comment: Eh...not sure I'd recommend this if Firefox is the only one to have implemented it. Glad to see it's part of the standard though; libraries always implement this themselves.

Comment: I think I will go with that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign Thanks again!

Comment: @Katana314: Given that we have polyfills, there is no reason not use new APIs. Transpilers even allow us to use new syntax and behavior. I believe it is on us to drive adoption here.

Comment: @FelixKling Point taken. Also, I failed to notice this was specifically a NodeJS question (I answer lots of browser JS questions), so there's no issue there.